# How can I filter both images and links using goutte?

Tags: php, laravel, goutte

I want to get list of both `img` and `a` from a website. I used the following code.

```
use Goutte\Client;
...
..
.
$client = new Client();
$url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/';
$page = $client->request('GET', $url);

$page->filter('img', 'a')->each(function ($item) use ($url) {
    dump($item->getNode(0));
});
```

However, it only shows the `img`; not `a`. If I use `$page->filter('a')` then I get all links. How can I get both imgs and as using one filter?

Comment: just replace`filter('img', 'a')` with `filter('img, a')`

Comment: thanks. it worked. 
you can add an answer if you want. I will mark it.

Comment: Yes, done. Forgot about that. Glad i could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace `filter('img', 'a')` with `filter('img, a')`.